# Replacing object_list with ListView: AttributeError

Tags: python, django, listview

I am trying to update a Django application to v1.6. When I replace the deprecated

```
return object_list(request,  template_name='generic_list.html', *args, **kwargs)
```

with

```
return ListView.as_view(template_name='generic_list.html', *args, **kwargs)
```

I get this error:

```
AttributeError at /assets/asset/list/
'function' object has no attribute 'status_code'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    `http://127.0.0.1:8000/assets/asset/list/`
Django Version: 1.6
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
'function' object has no attribute 'status_code'
Exception Location: c:\Program Files (x86)\Python\lib\site-packages\django\middleware\locale.py in process_response, line 41
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't say so, but you seem to be using the generic views at the end of an existing view. You wouldn't normally do that with a class-based generic view: the whole point of them being classes is that you can extend them by subclassing, adding your own functionality that way.

However, you can probably fix your immediate error in the short term by actually calling the view: what you are doing here is simply creating the view object (which itself is a callable). You still need to call that object, passing it the request and any params:

```
view = ListView.as_view(template_name='generic_list.html')
return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

But as I say I do not recommend doing that: you should subclass ListView and extend it.

Comment: I had to make a small change to what you wrote:
    view = ListView.as_view(template_name='generic_list.html', *args, **kwargs)
    return view(request)

Could you explain more about this error?